# NHibernate + Remoting = ReflectionPermission Exception

Tags: nhibernate, remoting, castle-dynamicproxy, system.security, reflectionpermission

We are dealing with a problem when using NHibernate with Remoting in a machine with full trust enviroment (actually that's our dev machine).

The problem happens when whe try to send as a parameter an object previously retrieved from the server, that contains a NHibernate Proxy in one of the properties (a lazy one).

As we are in the dev machine, there's no restriction in the trust level of the web app (it's set to Full) and, as a plus, we've configured NHibernate's and Castle's assemblies to full trust in CAS (even thinking that it'd not be necessary as the remoting app in IIS has the full trust level).

Does anyone have any idea of what can be causing this exception? Stack trace below.

```
  InnerException: System.Security.SecurityException
   Message="Falha na solicitação da permissão de tipo 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."
   Source="mscorlib"
   GrantedSet=""
   PermissionState="<IPermission class=\"System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\"\r\nversion=\"1\"\r\nFlags=\"ReflectionEmit\"/>\r\n"
   RefusedSet=""
   Url=""
   StackTrace:
        em System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
        em System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
        em System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternalNoLock(String name, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
        em System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternal(String name, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
        em System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(String name, Boolean emitSymbolInfo)
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.ModuleScope.CreateModule(Boolean signStrongName)
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.ModuleScope.ObtainDynamicModuleWithWeakName()
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.ModuleScope.ObtainDynamicModule(Boolean isStrongNamed)
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.ClassEmitter.CreateTypeBuilder(ModuleScope modulescope, String name, Type baseType, Type[] interfaces, TypeAttributes flags, Boolean forceUnsigned)
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.ClassEmitter..ctor(ModuleScope modulescope, String name, Type baseType, Type[] interfaces, TypeAttributes flags, Boolean forceUnsigned)
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.ClassEmitter..ctor(ModuleScope modulescope, String name, Type baseType, Type[] interfaces, TypeAttributes flags)
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.ClassEmitter..ctor(ModuleScope modulescope, String name, Type baseType, Type[] interfaces)
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.BuildClassEmitter(String typeName, Type parentType, Type[] interfaces)
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.BuildClassEmitter(String typeName, Type parentType, IList interfaceList)
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.ClassProxyGenerator.GenerateCode(Type[] interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.Serialization.ProxyObjectReference.RecreateClassProxy()
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.Serialization.ProxyObjectReference.RecreateProxy()
        em Castle.DynamicProxy.Serialization.ProxyObjectReference..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I work with Pedro, we found the problem: the serializer of the Remoting Service has to be explicit configured to allow full trust calls in the server side.

Something like (configuration file):

```
<channels>
<channel ref="http">
<serverProviders> 
<provider ref="wsdl" />
<formatter ref="soap" typeFilterLevel=Low />
<formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel=Low />
</serverProviders>
</channel>
</channels>
```

Or (programatically):

```
BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider provider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
provider.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;
```

Hope this helps anyone else.

Regards.